# Better about page example questions/answers/comments

Tags: support, help-pages

I [recently posted on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169946/197656) about the example questions, answers, and comments found on various site's about pages, and [was told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169950/197656) that although some sites have auto-system-picked examples, the mods of each site can change the example questions.

Currently, the following answer is featured on the Super User about page:

[image: I understand you can use the same mouse with different laptop with no ... port. When did the problem start? This is a weird one :P]

If you look at the [actual question's page](https://superuser.com/a/548957/171544), the answer shown as accepted on the about page is just another answer on the page. I don't frequent SU, but from the portion shown on the about page, that looks more like a comment than an answer. (If you look at the actual answer [actual answer](https://superuser.com/a/548957/171544), it has a few more the words that make it a possible answer rather than a comment, but these are hidden on the about page.)

Also, I'm probably being nitpicky on this one, but later on the about page, I saw this comment featured (Notice the bad grammar):
[image: i don't remember . more than 6 months .]

I don't frequent SU (I'm usually on SO), so maybe I'm missing something, but I think better examples could be chosen.

**Would the SU mods consider manually picking one of the best questions here to put on the about page to help new users better understand the site?**

Comment: We can totally change it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @nhinkle We can only choose from a limited set of questions. This query should give users the same list we see for picking questions: http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/92078/possible-about-questions

Comment: @nhinkle I'm not a frequent user of SU (I'm usually on SO), so it would probably be better to ask the SU community. Maybe another meta post?

Comment: We discussed this a while ago when the example question still was a made-up one about unicorns and daisies. I think having a small vote of some sort would be nice, but maybe we (mods) can come up with a pre-selection (otherwise voting might be a little inefficient), and then have a vote here.

Comment: @slhck Sounds like that would work. Didn't know that the question about unicorns and daisies was the default :D I saw it on the Code Golf about page and thought it was a question someone actually posted. (similar to a question about sorting socks [http://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881/1721527] on SO)

Comment: [Here's a modified version of that query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/101002/possible-about-questions) @slhck posted, showing a bit more data.

Comment: Maybe we can come up with 3-10 that we like, and put them up in a meta post for people to vote on?

Comment: @nhinkle That sounds like it will work. Possibly make the question explain the vote and put each possible example question as an answer to the meta post? That way the existing post voting mechanism could be used. (Though I guess that would let users add their own possibilities.)

Comment: @jdwire that's what I'm envisioning, yes.

Comment: I changed it to something else temporarily, that I think is a somewhat better question, but I still think we should have a proper vote on this.