# The example question on the tour is about unicorns

Tags: support, help-pages

The current example question on the [about page](https://superuser.com/tour) is the [Stack Exchange default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169946/better-about-page-example-questions-answers-comments) example: "How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies". This is quite unhelpful and makes the site look less professional.

[image: Unicorns on the about page]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guess we [forgot to update](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6430/better-about-page-example-questions-answers-comments) it.. I've set to a question from Super User now. Probably can change it to something else in required

Comment: weird it was not showing unicorns here, it was showing a , , , proper question (gone), now changed to the virtual machine question.  I lost what it was showing on the refresh, it was some shutdown or standby type of question.

Comment: @psy i updated the question couple of times

Comment: The unicorn question shows up when I open SE tour page. It is 3 years since it was changed (I suppose).